# Using array_column() in nested multi dimensional array to access dynamic indexes and values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-column

I have this nested multidimensional array for orders

```
[
    [
        'created_at' => 1991,
        'updated_at' => 1992,
        'customer_name' => 'john doe',
        'line_items' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Hello world poduct',
                'price' => 800.00,
                'id' => 123,
                'quantity' => 2
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Hello world product 2',
                'price' => 100.00,
                'id' => 456,
                'quantity' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'created_at' => 1992,
        'updated_at' => 1993,
        'customer_name' => 'Guido van Rossum',
        'line_items' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Hello world product',
                'price' => 800.00,
                'id' => 123,
                'quantity' => 2    
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Hello world poduct 2',
                'price' => 100.00,
                'id' => 456,
                'quantity' => 3
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Hello world poduct 3',
                'price' => 400.00,
                'id' => 116,
                'quantity' => 5
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

from this array I need to take the all the quantity values in to one array

This is what I've tried so far...

```
$newArr_items = array_column(array_column(array_column($result_3['orders'],'line_items'),'0'),'quantity');
```

but from this I can only take "0" th index values only, since this is dynamic array how can I correct my function to access quntity key of all the indexes

Comment: Thank you for your respond, but this gives me an empty array

Comment: Just use `array_walk_recursive()`.

Comment: I don't see why Anant's advice is unsuitable.  Please provide `var_export($result_3);` so that we can run a demo of Anant's advice to prove that it works.  Does there need to be an `array_merge()` in between `array_column()` calls?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/I9X9N

Comment: Ah yeah, just needed a flattening `array_merge()` in the middle. https://3v4l.org/Y65Sf

Comment: @mickmackusa array_merge() has fixed the issue, please post this as an answer then I can accept it as the correct answer!

Comment: erm... I don't know. I'm torn.  It is resolved by the dupes, but my advice is not necessarily suitable as an answer on the dupes.  Let me confer with SOCVR.

Comment: I know you are looking for a particular value, but isn't that loosing the context of that quantity doesn't take into account the product it's for.

Comment: Agreed here with @NigelRen. after getting all quantities value in a single array, you don't know which quantity is attached to which product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the `line_items` data, then flatten that indexed payload with `array_merge()` and the splat operator, then you can access the `quantity` column with another call of `array_column()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y65Sf))

```
var_export(
    array_column(
        array_merge(
            ...array_column($array, 'line_items')
        ),
        'quantity'
    )
);
```